# New instance of fragment gets created on application launch

Tags: android, fragment

I have a single fragment loaded in an activity using fragment manager inside a container layout. Inside my activity i start a service to connect to other bluetooth device and communicate with it by sending and receiving certain data. Everything works fine when the app is open and the service is connected to bluetooth device.

But when i hit back button and reopen my app , though my service is still connected to other bluetooth device the fragment i'm using to display the same shows it is in disconnected state.
I put a check before setting the text to my fragment's child textview using

> fragment.isVisible()

and it returned false (?)

So , i think if i'm not wrong , the activity is creating a different instance of fragment over my original fragment everytime i open the app.

Here is the onCreate() of my activity..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt_dashboard);

    System.out.println("OnCreate() of BTDashboardActivity........");

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            System.out.println("ListFragmetn allready exist...");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("adding listfragment to view...");

        listFragment = new BTDashboardListFragment();

        listFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, listFragment).commit();

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

here is code for onStart() of activity..

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent,
                    Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            if (mBluetoothService == null) {
                startBluetoothService();
                Log.d(TAG, "Chat service Started...@@@@@@@@@@@@");

                showDisconnectedUI();

            System.out.println("showing disconnceted status to the user..");

            } else {
                if (mBluetoothService.getState() == Constants.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                System.out.println("showing connection status to the user..");
                    showConnectedUI();

                } else {

            System.out.println("showing disconnceted status to the user..");
                    showDisconnectedUI();

                }
            }

        }
```

}

And this is code to set data to fragment's child views..

```
protected void handleResponse(String readMessage) {


    System.out.println("response from device: " + readMessage);

    if (readMessage != null) {

         if (listFragment != null && listFragment.isInLayout()) {
         System.out.println("List fragment is found...");

        System.out.println("Setting response text to listFragment...");



        if(listFragment.isVisible())   // prints not visible after reopening the app
            System.out.println("listFragment is visible ...");
        else
            System.out.println("listFragment is not visible..."); 

        listFragment.setResponseText(readMessage);

        }
              }
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I think, you should work with the BlueTooth code to use some checks.
Of-course, when the onCreate is called new instance of Fragments will be created and you are right but as the Service is still active, its essential for you to put some checks for "enabled device pairing" state between those two devices. I think this can make some change.

Comment: thanks for the comment but blutooth connection is not my problem. the connection remains in established state even when i hit back button and reopen the app.. The problem is that the fragment i'm trying to update is not visible anymore ..(may be a new instance is getting placed over it and i'm playing with older one which is below new fragment)

Comment: Purushottam, i am asking you to maintain the Bluetooth checks, like if device are paired then move...can we do it?

Comment: oh .. i got it now.. yes we can do that and i think i'm already doing it. Checking the state of bluetooth connection in onStart and showing respective ui's accordingly .. see edit section of question..

Comment: whenever you press your back key, just check that you are not re-initializing the "socket to null" on onDestroy. ??

Comment: the bluetooth connection is intact. i'm pretty sure that going to background or closing the app doesnt interfere with my bluetooth connection. infact I'm able to read the response from device in logs but unable to display it on the fragment because its invisible..

Comment: You need to check your Socket connection, may be it is the problem, as am experienced, that was the problem with me too few days ago. Sorry but I can't help much.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the fragment instance **static** solved my problem. 
I know this is just a workaround 
but works like a charm for me right now..

Comment: can you please help me , i am loading some functionality in a fragment and its get re created when i switch back to my fragment !!